# T4 templates: Error on namespace

Tags: t4

I am trying to write a class in T4 template. It gives the error:

```
Compiling transofrmation: Type of namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

if I have the following code:

```
<#+
namespace Learn {
    public class Converter
    {

    }
}
#>
```

But it works fine if I remove namespace

```
<#+
    public class Converter
    {

    }
#>
```

My question is, why T4 doesn't recognize the `namespace`?

Comment: Because code within `<# #>` is not code that is being generated but code that is being run to generate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<#+ #> is a class feature block.  Anything you put inside this block will be written inside a class statement.  When you add a namespace T4 will generate and try to compile something like this:

```
class MyT4TempGen {

     public string run() {
          inside here is code that uses a string builder to build up all your <# #> tags into one big statement
     }

     from here down all your <#+ #> tags are added

     namespace Learn {
        public class Converter {

        }
     } 

}
```

This is not valid C# code, namespaces can not exist within a class statement.  When you do it without the namespace you will get this:

```
class MyT4TempGen {

     public string run() {
         inside here is code that uses a string builder to build up all your <# #> tags into one big statement
     }

     from here down all your <#+ #> tags are added         

     public class Converter {

     }

}
```

Which is valid c# code, your class will be a sub class of the one the T4 compiler creates.

Here is a link to the [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126478.aspx) that explain the supported tags. See the section "Class feature control blocks".  Just remember that whatever you type into a tt or t4 file will be parsed and turned into .net code so you have to follow all the normal syntax rules.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Frank, that explains things.